# Indy TLS Server "No shared cipher" using ECDH Keys

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, indy10, ecdh

Hoping someone out there can help me with this one. Simple `TIdHTTPServer` with OpenSSL support used to decode TLS traffic from a client using ECDH-based keys.

Server key created with the following command:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
```

Server debug logs:

```
23:33:14.878 SSL status: "before/accept initialization"
23:33:14.886 SSL status: "SSLv3 read client hello C"
23:33:14.886 SSL status: "error"
23:33:14.887 Connection from: 192.168.12.1:23727 Closed
23:33:14.887 EXCEPTION: Error accepting connection with SSL.
error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360491/), it seems like I need to call `SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx,1)`

SSL Server Initialization:

```cpp
ServerIOHandler = new TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL();
ServerIOHandler->SSLOptions->CertFile = CertPath;
ServerIOHandler->SSLOptions->KeyFile = KeyPath;
ServerIOHandler->SSLOptions->RootCertFile = RootCertPath;
ServerIOHandler->SSLOptions->Method = sslvTLSv1_2;
ServerIOHandler->SSLOptions->Mode = sslmServer;
//ServerIOHandler->SSLOptions->CipherList = "";
ServerIOHandler->SSLOptions->VerifyDepth = 1;
ServerIOHandler->OnGetPassword = OnGetServerPassword;

ServerIOHandler->OnStatusInfo = SSL_Status;

TLSServer->Bindings->Add();
TLSServer->Bindings->Items[0]->IP = TLSServerInfo.AdapterIP;
TLSServer->Bindings->Items[0]->Port = TLSServerInfo.LocalPort;
TLSServer->DefaultPort = TLSServerInfo.LocalPort;

TLSServer->IOHandler = ServerIOHandler;

try {
   PanelServer->Active = true;
}
catch (Exception &Ex) {
    Msg = String(L"SSL Server Bound Exception: ") + Ex.Message;
}
```

I have followed [these instructions](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.tools/support-for-perfect-forward-secrecy/2031813) to add `SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()` to my `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` file, but if I try to add an entry to call `SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()` from my code, I get a "Call to undefined function 'SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto'" error.

I am running Indy 10.6.2.

[image: TLS Handshake]

Comment: If you had upgraded your Indy, like the 1st linked question said to do, you would not have had to add `SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()` to your`IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` manually, as it already exists, as has for the past 3 years. Is there a problem following the instructions in the 1st linked question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Perfect Forward Secrecy In Indy 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360491/how-to-enable-perfect-forward-secrecy-in-indy-10)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have installed RAD Studio 10.3.3 (Rio) on another machine to avoid stuffing up my main dev PC. First problem I ran into was the ` EFOpenError with message 'Cannot open file...` fixed that with this [patch](https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/attachment/28096/IndySSL.patch) then went about downloading Indy project from [here]( https://web.archive.org/web/20180716164622if_/https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy) Eventually got it rebuilt and the bpl's re-imported etc, now I'm back to the ` EFOpenError with message 'Cannot open file...` issue...

Comment: Why are you using a 2 1/2 year old archived copy of the repo, instead of the latest repo? https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy

Comment: Good point, just ended up at the archive after trying to follow dead ww2 Indy links, I cloned the project from your link and rebuilt it but still get the certificate load errors: [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmE9EcqIi3_Bhs58_-uTXkPcfyg9-g?e=RWNbtk)

Comment: You should not be getting that kind of error with the latest code in Indy's repo, only if you were still using Embarcadero's botched code that they had to release a patch for. The original repo code does not suffer from that encoding issue, Embarcadero had modified the code and introduced the error in their copy of Indy.

Comment: Agreed had this issue when building the project with a brand new RAD Studio 10.3.3 (Community Edition) setup then applied the patch to `IdSSLOpenSSL.pas` which removed the certificate load problem. I'll most probably move to a pure C++ solution for this project as this problem has stumped me. Thanks for the help in any case

Comment: My point was, if you are getting the error, you are likely compiling against the stock unpatched version that shipped with RAD Studio, not the patched or repo version.  Which might imply that you are not replacing the stock version with the repo version correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I installed C++ Builder v10.4  (Indy 10.6.2.0) it has SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto defined in 'IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas' please show me how to call SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto from my C++ project as I get "Call to undefined function 'SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto'" when trying to call it

Comment: `SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto` is declared with [`{$EXTERNALSYM}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/External_Symbols_(Delphi)) in `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas`, so it does not exist in `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.hpp`. In C++, you are expected to use OpenSSL's own C/C++ header files.

Comment: Thanks Remy will look into this method

Comment: Ended up using this library: [http://www.overbyte.eu/frame_index.html](http://www.overbyte.eu/frame_index.html)