# Enable Perfect Forward Secrecy In Indy 10?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, indy

In [How to enable Perfect Forward Secrecy In Indy 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360491/), the question is answered for Delphi. As I am trying to achieve the same in C++, I get stuck at the `SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()` method. It is present in the source of Indy, and thus (I assume) in the installed version (I am running C++Builder 11), but there is no reference in the C++ header file `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.hpp`.

However, I might add this manually in the header, assuming the DCU contains the source, but searching the web for OpenSSL I found [`SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()` and `SSL_set_ecdh_auto()` are deprecated and have no effect](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto.html).

How can I best enable perfect forward secrecy using C++ and Indy 10?

```cpp
TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL * LIOHandleSSL;
LIOHandleSSL = new TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL(FServer);
LIOHandleSSL->SSLOptions->Mode = TIdSSLMode::sslmServer;
LIOHandleSSL->SSLOptions->Method = TIdSSLVersion::sslvTLSv1_2;
LIOHandleSSL->SSLOptions->SSLVersions = TIdSSLVersions() << TIdSSLVersion::sslvTLSv1_2;
LIOHandleSSL->SSLOptions->CertFile = AppRoot + CertFile;
if (RootCertFile.Trim().Length() > 0)
    LIOHandleSSL->SSLOptions->RootCertFile = AppRoot + RootCertFile;
LIOHandleSSL->SSLOptions->KeyFile = AppRoot + KeyFile;

LIOHandleSSL->SSLOptions->CipherList = ""
"ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
"ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:"
"HIGH:"
"!aNULL:"
"!eNULL:"
"!EXPORT:"
"!DES:"
"!RC4:"
"!MD5:"
"!PSK:"
"!SRP:"
"!CAMELLIA:"
"@STRENGTH";

// this is what is needed according to the post
//               auto sslContext = TMyIdSSLContext(LIOHandleSSL->SSLContext);
//             SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(FSSLContext.fContext, 1);

LIOHandleSSL->OnGetPassword = OnGetSSLPassword;

FServer->IOHandler = LIOHandleSSL;
FServer->OnQuerySSLPort = OnQuerySSLPort;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [`SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()`] is present in the source of Indy, and thus (I assume) in the installed version (I am running C++Builder 11), but there is no reference in the C++ header file `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.hpp`.

That is because all of the OpenSSL functions used in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` unit are marked as [`{$EXTERNALSYM}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/External_Symbols_(Delphi)) specifically so that they *won't* appear in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.hpp` file.  This is customary when Delphi units use external SDKs that are otherwise available to C/C++ natively.

So, to use the OpenSSL functions in C++, you will have to download the OpenSSL 1.0.2 SDK and `#include` its `.h` header files in your code (or, as you said, you can simply declare the functions yourself, since they are present in the Delphi DCUs). Delphi can't use `.h` files, which is (mostly) why `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` exists.

> searching the web for OpenSSL I found `SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()` and `SSL_set_ecdh_auto()` are deprecated and have no effect.

In OpenSSL 1.1.0 and later, yes.  But not in OpenSSL 1.0.2, which is what `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` uses.  If you want to use OpenSSL 1.1.x+, you need to use [this (wip) `SSLIOHandler`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead.

> ```
> // this is what is needed according to the post
> //               auto sslContext = TMyIdSSLContext(LIOHandleSSL->SSLContext);
> //             SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(FSSLContext.fContext, 1);
> ```

In C++, that would look something like this:

```cpp
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
// or simply:
// long __fastcall SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(PSSL_CTX ctx, long m);

class TMyIdSSLContext : public TIdSSLContext
{
public:
    __property PSSL_CTX Context = {read=fContext};
};

auto sslContext = (TMyIdSSLContext*) LIOHandleSSL->SSLContext;
SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(sslContext->Context, 1);
```

Comment: `// or simply:`
`// long __fastcall SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(PSSL_CTX ctx, long m);`

gives me an unresolved external i now placed it in the header of the Unit where I placed the auto sslContent = .... in the source. 

where exactly should i place long __fastcall SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(PSSL_CTX ctx, long m); (in what file/location ?)

Comment: on the other suggestion to use TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL instead of TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL. can i just use the oter class and if so how do i connect this to my FServer->IOHandler (TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge) for this property is of a different type ?

Comment: "*on the other suggestion to use TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL instead of TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL*" - I made no such suggestion. The code in question is accessing the `SSLContext->Context` of a ServerIOHandler.

Comment: I am really appreciate the reply but although i believe this is the solution i am unable to get it to work. 
Adding :
`long __fastcall SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(PSSL_CTX ctx, long m);`
to the header where (frmMainUnit.h for testing) gives an unresolved external so i cannot figure out what I am missing. I do not have much experience with including external libs so i might be missing the required step. any help to further my progress would be very much appreciated.